# Does vim support non-ASCII commands?

Tags: vim, localization

I often write text in Russian. I use `set langmap` for translating Russian characters to English, so commands like `i` and `d` work also in a Russian layout.

But it does not work for a command started from `:` like `:wq` -- vim translates `Ж` to `:` as described in langmap, but other characters are unaffected, and I want to use `:цй` instead `:wq`.

I tried to use `:command цй wq` to make alias, but take `E182: Invalid comand name`.

Do you have ideas on how to translate `Жцй` to `:wq`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `cmap` or `cabbrev`. For example

```
cmap цй wq

cabbrev цй wq
```

`cabbrev` is probably what you want since you don't have to enter a <kbd>Space</kbd> afterwards.

Comment: Should mention the downside that this (the `cmap` more than the `cabbrev`) affects all occurrences in the command-line, also searching via /. I usually recommend the cmdalias plugin in these cases, but it unfortunately only supports ASCII word characters as alias names.

Comment: Thank you, `cabbrev` works for me. It affects commands like `/`, but "цй" is very unusual sequence of characters in Russian text, so I don't mind.